# XCpretty generate an empty HTML report

Tags: xcode, static, code-analysis

I want to generate Xcode static analysis HTML report. I have installed `xcpretty` and generated the report by running the following commands:

1. `$ gem install xcpretty`
2. `xcpretty $ xcodebuild [flags] | xcpretty -r html`

The problem is that it generates an empty html report, any help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with generating junit style reports.

In Xcode

1. List item
2. Edit Schema
3. Select Tests
4. Open up options
5. Disable Execute in Parallel on Simulator.

That fixed the empty junit style report for me. Good luck.